# Ajax request POST returns 403 error, GET returns 200 ok on same url

Tags: ajax, post, prestashop

I'm trying to set up a prestashop webshop and I bought a theme to customize it. Instalation works great, but when reaching the live edit module of the theme I ran into a problem: after customizing the layout I tried to save my modifications, but it returns with 403 error. I've tried to debug it, I've contacted my hosting, I've contacted the developer of the theme, but noone can help me. In the error logs doesn't appear anything regarding this issue. The developer says it is tested on multiple hosts, and it works great. My host says they can't do anything if there is no error message in the logs.

I've managed to circle down the issue a little bit. There is a larger sized parameter(it contains all new configurations) which if I disable to be sent, then I get the following error: "Your hosting provider has set a non-standard or too little value of parameter LimitRequestLine in httpd.conf. Set the default setting  value of parameter LimitRequestLine in httpd.conf, please." This error I receive on post and get aswell.

This parameter can be the source of my problem if the http call is through ajax post? Or there is more this issue?

I'm trying to solve this issue for 3 months now, I've spoken to the hosting firm, I've spoken to the developer of the them, I've searched a lot of forums but found no answer to this. I'm desperate to get any help on this matter.

Comment: It looks like I solved the issue with the following codes:

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I solved the issue with the following codes:

1. **/public_html/modules/ixtengine/js/cpanel/cpanel.min.js**

... `,$.ajax({type:"POST",url:cpfuncurl+previewfun,data:{` ...

replaced by

... `,$.ajax({type:"PUT",url:cpfuncurl+previewfun,data:{` ...

and

... `,$.ajax({type:"POST",url:cpfuncurl+savefun,data:{` ...

replaced by

... `,$.ajax({type:"PUT",url:cpfuncurl+savefun,data:{` ...

2. **/public_html/modules/ixtengine/cpanel/functions/upload.savepf.php** and **/public_html/modules/ixtengine/cpanel/functions/upload.previewwid.php**

...

`$theme = Tools::getValue('theme');`

`$conf = Tools::getValue('conf');`

`$skin = Tools::getValue('skin');`

`$skinid = Tools::getValue('skinid');`

`$token = Tools::getValue('token');`

...

replaced by

...

`$put_vars=array();`

`if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT')`

`{`

`parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$put_vars);`

`$theme = $put_vars['theme'];`

`$conf = $put_vars['conf'];`

`$skin = $put_vars['skin'];`

`$skinid = $put_vars['skinid'];`

`$token = $put_vars['token'];`

`}`

`else`

`{`

`$theme = Tools::getValue('theme');`

`$conf = Tools::getValue('conf');`

`$skin = Tools::getValue('skin');`

`$skinid = Tools::getValue('skinid');`

`$token = Tools::getValue('token');`

`}`

...

This solution is particulary for the ixtengine module for some hosts where POST returns 403 error so I can't be sure if this method will work for someone else running into this problem, but it works for me.